# use linux join command to update fields in text file if value exists

Tags: join, text-processing, gnu-coreutils

I have two very large text files where file2 has "updates and new items"
Eg:
file1:

```
itemA,ABC,123
itemB,,456
itemC,XYZ,789
```

file2:

```
itemB,DEF,456
itemC,XYZ,567
itemD,321,ZYX
```

I want my final output to be:

```
itemA,ABC,123
itemB,DEF,456
itemC,XYZ,567
itemD,321,ZYX
```

So it would add any new lines, but replace info for any existing lines.
Can this be done with coreutils (join, paste, merge, etc)?
Or am I better off loading it into a db, doing INSERT/ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE and dumping it out?

Comment: How large is "very large"?

Comment: very large = over 100GB

Comment: I would think you'll really need to stash that into a db. You'll have trouble using command line tools with that much data, unless your machine is stuffed with RAM.

Comment: I did, indeed, go with a db. That seems to be the only real option with this amount of data

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that file2 is smaller than file1, since it's the "new or updated" records. I'm assuming also that it's small enough to fit comfortably in memory.

With awk: this stores the file2, based on field 1 being the unique id.

- If field 1 appears in both file1 and file2, then file2 record is printed.
- If field 1 appeard in just file1, that record is printed.
- After processing file1, any records from file2 that do not appear in file1 are printed.

```
awk -F, '
    NR == FNR {f2[$1] = $0; next} 
    $1 in f2 {print f2[$1]; delete f2[$1]; next} 
    1
    END {for (key in f2) print f2[key]}
' file2 file1
```

outputs

```
itemA,ABC,123
itemB,DEF,456
itemC,XYZ,567
itemD,321,ZYX
```

It just happens to be sorted, you might want to pipe the output into `sort` if it's important for you.

---

Here's a version with `join` and awk: join requires the input files to be sorted

```
$ join -t, -a1 -a2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print $1, $(NF-1), $NF}'
itemA,ABC,123
itemB,DEF,456
itemC,XYZ,567
itemD,321,ZYX
```